# Valor duplicado na tabela. Como remover?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Inseri umas tabelas do TSE no meu banco de dados e tem valores duplicados da coluna `SQ_CANDIDATO` que representa a imagem colocada acima. Como posso fazer uma manutenção com ***sql*** que vai remover ***TODOS*** os valores duplicados independente da ***ID***?

... Deixar somente um registro `SQ_CANDIDATO` para cada ***ID*** ...

Comment: não seria melhor por ela unica nao?

Comment: [*Possível solução*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3312066/1244639)

Comment: Veja se ajuda  http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/532628-deletar-registros-duplicados/    http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/530320-valores-duplicados/

Comment: Marcos removi a tag PHP da sua questão por não ter nenhuma relação com a sua dúvida a linguagem em si.

Comment: Veja se este link te ajuda...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode montar um subselect dentro do delete selecionando as linhas cujos `sq_candidato` são repetidos:

```
delete from candidatos where id in(
    select candidatos.id from candidatos
    inner join candidatos c on c.sq_candidato = candidatos.sq_candidato
    where c.id <> candidatos.id
    group by candidatos.sq_candidato
);
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/xWWJ6V). (SQLFiddle está dando timeout)

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE T2 /*Isto aqui define a tabela que terá o registro apagado*/
FROM candidatos T1
INNER JOIN candidados T2
ON T1.SQ_CANDIDATO = T2.SQ_CANDIDATO
AND T1.id < T2.id /*Isto aqui é para evitar que o JOIN faça select duas vezes no mesmo registro, isto é, uma vez em T1 e outra em T2, usando-se '>' ou '<', então o registro só aparecerá uma vez, então o desempenho do select será  maior e apenas um registro será apagado*/
```